# A word for these kind of categories: Ongoing Series, Limited Series and One Shot

Tags: single-word-requests

In comic books common terms are 1[. ongoing series, 2. limited series and 3. one shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ongoing_series).

I'm looking for a word that defines what these categories are examples of, what type of division is this?

"Series type" or "Media Format" seem very general.

Thanks for your help!